# How do I import a 3rd party contract ABI in solidity/truffle?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, dapps

I'm using Truffle to compile my contracts. I'd like to create an instance of a contract compiled and deployed previously by someone else so that I can interact with it.

Can this be done without recompiling their entire contract? I assume I would just need the ABI, which I can grab from etherscan.

tl;dr how do I take an ABI from etherscan and then, in solidity, instantiate an instance of it at a particular deployed address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of Truffle [v5.1.52](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.1.52),  you can import ABI JSON files directly from Solidity if they are in your `contracts/` folder.

```
import "./Uniswap.abi.json";
```

Under the hood, truffle uses https://github.com/gnidan/abi-to-sol